# How to sort products by Custom Attributes?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is there a way to sort products by any custom attribute? For example, sort by category, brand or colour?

I assume that I should create the attribute and set it to be "Used for Sorting in Product Listing".

I would like to sort products by the following attributes:

gender first, then brand, category and lastly colour.

The question is how do I use these attributes to sort the products in the backend so that they are visible in the frontend in that order?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

Create a phtml file (sort.phtml) under catalog\product\list.

Contain of  sort.phtml is

```
<div class="sort-by">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

After that call this file in list.phtml using below codes-

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_list_toolbar")->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/sort.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Hope this code will be working